# I can't access my winsock server from another computer (but localhost works)

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, winsock, winsock2

I can't connect to my winsock server (tcp/ip) from another computer but I can on localhost using putty. The machine I use is running linux and I'm using putty on it to connect to my server. I don't know if I can't connect because my computer is running linux or because I made a mistake in my code so I need your help.

Server.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int main()
{
    std::cout << "--- Tcp/ip Server ---" << std::endl;
    WSADATA wsa;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa);

    SOCKET server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (server == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout << "error in SOCKET(): "<< WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
    }
    sockaddr_in s;
    s.sin_family = AF_INET;
    s.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    s.sin_port = htons(52000);

    // bind
    if (bind(server, (sockaddr*)&s, sizeof(s)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: bind()" << std::endl;
    }
    //listen
    if (listen(server, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "Error in listen(): " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
    }
    sockaddr_in from;
    int fromlen = sizeof(from);
    // accept
    SOCKET client = accept(server, (SOCKADDR*)&from, &fromlen);
    if (client == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout << "Error in accept(): " << WSAGetLastError << std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
    }
    else
    {

        char clientIp[17];
        if (inet_ntop(AF_INET, &from.sin_addr, clientIp, 17) == NULL)
        {
            std::cout << "Can't get the client's ip: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << "ip connected: " << clientIp << std::endl;
    }
    char recvbuf[512];
    do
    {
        int iResult = recv(client, recvbuf, 512, 0);
        if (iResult > 0)
        {
            send(client, recvbuf, iResult, 0);
        }


    } while (true);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start by checking firewall settings on both computers. Taking a look at what's going over the network with Wireshark also wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Unrelated: Probably want some `return <error code>;`s after the calls to `WSACleanup`. Not much point trying to continue with the program after that.

Comment: ok I'll try that

Comment: Not seeing anything wrong that should halt a connection. There is a call to `WSAGetLastError` missing brackets but that'll just mess up an error code and the `do/while(true);` has no exit condition so it'll spin uselessly FOREVER!!!! when the connection ends, but nothing that should fail without you seeing at least one diagnostic.

Comment: Oh and I'll lose my nerd membership card if I don't quote Yoda at you. Sorry. "No. Try not. Do... Or do not. There is no try."

Comment: @user4581301 I checked my connection with netstat on both computers and for the windows computer (server) I get this when the connection is established (using PuTTY in localhost): `TCP    127.0.0.1:52000        127.0.0.1:54688        ESTABLISHED` . For the linux computer, I get this when I try to connect to 198.168.2.23 on port 52000: `tcp    0    1  192.168.2.20::45625    198.168.2.23::52000     SYN_SENT` and after a few minutes I see a PuTTY Fatal Error: connection timed out.

Comment: Launch Wireshark on the PC and see if it's even seeing the SYN packets from the Linux PC. If it's not, you're getting blocked somewhere. Definitely make sure 52000 is open in the firewall.

Comment: @user4581301 you're right it's probably because of a firewall. I will look how to change the firewall settings or how to bypass it.

Comment: @user4581301 I tried to use wireshark but the windows pc did not see anything so i opened port 52000 in the firewall but it still does not work so I just wanted to be sure I opened port 52000 correctly (I'm from Quebec so my settings are in french but don't worry I did the translation for you. https://imgur.com/a/yhbOYv3

Comment: That looks good to me. Are you able to turn off the firewall entirely for a few seconds to quickly test and see if the firewall can be eliminated  as a problem? No worries about the French. My French sucks, but I'm still Canadian enough to read that.

Comment: @user4581301 Sure I will try that.

Comment: @user4581301 I really do not understand why but it still does not work.

Comment: Running out of things to try.  I've run your code from my Windows box and connected and echoed from a SUSE Linux box..Are you absolutely positive you have the correct IP address for the Windows PC?  The Telnet client on the Linux box has outbound permissions through the firewall?

Comment: @user4581301 I'm sure I have the correct ip address but I'm not sure that the client has outbound permissions through the firewall. Tbh I don't even know how to check that it has this permissions on linux. (does it change depending on the distro?)

Comment: Unfortunately it can. Different distributions use different firewalls.

Comment: @user4581301 OMG I finally managed to get it working! I found that I had another firewall that I probably installed many years ago and that I had forgot about. Thank you so much for helping me to solve this problem. It was highly appreciated!